# Storing encryption keys for desktop application(Email Client)[Duplication]

Tags: encryption, configuration, desktop-application, key-management

There are so many articles on stack-overflow and security.stackexchange on storing encryption keys, but I am still confused, so that's why I decided to ask again here.

Basically, I am creating an Email client for education purpose, in that Users can create account where they enter there Email-ID and Password. I am looking for secure way to save the information.

I will be

1. Encrypting the Email-ID and Password
2. and storing the encryption key on the user PC because I don't want the user to type in password every time he sends and Email

From reading I have understood that,

1. I need to store the encryption key in a separate location, so that it will be difficult to find by an hacker, But the problem here is that my application is written in Python and it will be open source application, so hacker can view the source code and get the path of the directory where the key is stored.
2. Second solution is that I can have a master password which will be used as a key, when the user opens the application for the first time after starting the computer, the application will ask for the master password, then I can store the key in RAM.

Looking at all the articles on internet on this topic this is a repetition, but I am sill learning to make applications and for the last two days I going in a loop with no success.

OS: Linux Ubuntu 14.04

Programming Language/Framework: Python/Gtk+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is correct.

It's impossible to prevent a attacker with access to the local key from accessing the password. Obscuring the path where it is stored provides virtually zero additional security - any attacker with the know-how necessary to perform the decryption will easily bypass such a mechanism.

The only secure way to do this is storing the key (or a key to the key) *out* of the computer - in the user's mind, in the case of the master password mechanism.

If you end up using a master password, don't forget to use a proper [key derivation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function), ideally with a [key-stretching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching) mechanism, such as PBKDF2 or bcrypt. **Never use a password as a key directly** (or even a simple hash of the password.

Comment: I guess, I will go with master password, till I find a better solution.